# Access Git in Ubuntu subsystem (Windows 11) from the local network

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Linux subsystem for Windows 11 in my O.S.

I've installed a Git repository in that Linux.
It works great from Windows, so I can clone the repository and pull/push files from Windows tools (`git clone \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\myuser\projects\myproject.git`)

My question is, what is the best way to access that repository from other computer in the local network?

Comment: I mean pull, push and clone operations. The tricky thing is make this internal service in the Linux subsystem accessible from other computers in the local network

Answer (score 0):

heck if you can [map `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` to a drive letter](https://superuser.com/a/1739762/141), and share that drive (to be accessible from your LAN)

Then, from another computer, you could `git clone \\yourComputer\Z$\path\to\repo`

If not, you can `git clone --bare \\wsl$\Ubuntu\path\to\repo C:\sharedFolder\repo.git`, establishing a **[bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)** in `C:\sharedFolder`, and cloning from your LAN `\\yourComputer\sharedFolder\repo.git`

The advantage with this approach is the ability to push back (to a bare repository). Add a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) on that bare `repo.git/hookpost-receive`, and said `post-receive` script can in turn cd to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\path\to\repo` and do a git pull, automatically updating your original WSL2 repository when your LAN pushes to the bare repository.